# Persistent Drawer not working with material-ui v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying the Persistent Drawer example as it is in the documentation https://next.material-ui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer, but it's not compiling.

```
/Users/alex/Dev/wnav-react2/src/App.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/alex/Dev/wnav-react2/src/App.tsx(24,15):
Property 'open' does not exist on type '{ theme?: Theme | undefined; as?: ElementType<any> | undefined; sx?: SxProps<Theme> | undefined; } & ClassAttributes<HTMLElement> & HTMLAttributes<...> & { ...; }'.  TS2339

    22 | 
    23 | const Main = styled('main', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  > 24 |     ({ theme, open }) => ({
       |               ^
    25 |       flexGrow: 1,
    26 |       padding: theme.spacing(3),
    27 |       transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
```

Any clue what could be the error?

package.json:

```
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
```

Comment: I've logged an issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27835. You can find the correct TypeScript code in the repository here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-beta.4/docs/src/pages/components/drawers/PersistentDrawerLeft.tsx.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
yarn add @mui/material @mui/icons-material @mui/styles
```